# Is it customary to report a beta coefficient for ANCOVA?

Tags: ancova

I'm reviewing a paper for a journal, and the authors have reported results of ANCOVA models. They report the F statistic, partial eta squared, beta coefficient, standard error, p value, and R squared. My question is, is it customary to report a beta coefficient for ANCOVA? In my reading, I've only been able to find instances of authors providing the F statistic and the p value, and I don't have experience using ANCOVA myself.

Comment: It's not customary, but it's annoying when people don't.

Answer (score 1):

ANCOVA simply means they used another variable (covariate) to adjust their ANOVA model, similar to an example that incorporates age (covariate) into an ANOVA model for systolic blood pressure = Drug treatment (placebo, treated) and gender, since SBP correlates with age.

It would be useful to know if the main effect, i.e., drug teatment in this example, was significant and that it's coefficient was negative, meaning it reduced SBP, and it was significant (p-value less than 0.05). As you know, if a drug is effective for treating hypertension, it would lower SBP (so a negative drug coefficient).

In any ANOVA, ANCOVA, or regression mode, what's important is

- sign of the coeff (+/-) (i.e. did drug elevate or reduce SBP)
- magnitude of coeff (how large of a mean change, if it's 0.0001 $\rightarrow$ "so what")
- p-value for coeff.

Next comes the p-value for the overall F-test, which portrays whether all the coefficients are significant (except the Constant term, or y-intcp).  So yes, the p-value for the F-test can be significant, but it may not be if the other "adjusting variables" or the covariate is not.  But the main effect (main experimental variable) should be significant.

Whenever you add variables to models, coefficients and p-values for variables often change, and this is usually addressed in the off-topic called "effect modification vs. confounding."  In other words, the covariate mentioned in the manuscript could be an effect modifier or a confounder, which is not what you're asking -- but I wanted to raise this issue since modeling always drags you deeper into the "rabbit hole" of model-building complexity.

FYI - I never call anything being reviewed a "paper," until it's accepted.  Before they are accepted, and during review, they should be called "manuscripts."

Comment: Right, I'm reviewing a manuscript for a journal, not a paper! Thanks. In this case, the authors report one p-value, and I'm assuming it's the p-value for the coefficient, not for the overall F test. One further question - shouldn't 95% CIs be presented as well?

Comment: Hopefully, it's the p-value for the main coefficient, not the covariate.  Unless they're trying to prove the covariate is a significant contributor (doubt it).  No, they don't have to report the 95%CI, only if it was a hazard ratio (from Cox regression), odds ratio (from logistic regression, epi table, Mantel-Haenzel), or relative risk (from Poisson regression).